# XPath string modification using regex, Java

Tags: java, regex, xpath

Say I have an XPath string like `/Results/Bill[Item[id]]/id`. I need to add namespace information to the path, so that the path is transformed to this: `/*:Results/*:Bill[*:Item[*:id]]/*:id`.

I was thinking of use regex to do this, something like "prepend "*:" to any alphanumeric character that is not preceded by another alphanumeric character". However, I don't have very much regex knowledge and don't know what regex this would correspond to (I'm planning to use Java's `replaceAll()` function once I have the regex). Also, can anyone think of a counter example where my idea wouldn't work? I'll just be performing the replacement operation on XPath strings with simple predicates (i.e. no `and`, `or` etc in between the square brackets).

Comment: Replace `\w+`  with `*:$0` if all you need is prepend `*:` to any alphanumeric/underscore words.

Answer (score 1):

You might get a regex solution to work with some kind of subset of XPath expressions, but you will never get it to work with all XPath expressions. The XPath grammar is just too complicated.

(The most obvious bugs in your initial proposal are that it fails on variable names like `$var`, function names like `count(..)` and axis names like `parent::*` or `@code`. You could solve that by checking for the relevant punctuation before or after the symbol. Checking for text inside comments or string literals is a bit trickier. But distinguishing "div" as an element name from "div" as an operator is way beyond what a regex approach can do: it needs a full context-sensitive parser.)

Better suggestion: use a tool that gives you a parse tree for the XPath expression, modify that parse tree, and then re-serialize the modified tree into XPath syntax.

See for example what can be done with Gunther Rademacher's Rex tool, or with the W3C XQuery parser applets (both easily found with google).